# PHP - Переход на страницу при условии из формы

Tags: php, javascript, html, поиск

Есть форма, допустим два селекта:

```
select=спальни name=badrooms   option выбор 1,2,3 
select=душевые name=showers    option выбор 1,2

input type=submit value=Search
```

и есть HTML страницы с данными критериями поиска. Как можно осуществить переход на эти HTMLстраницы, например при условии:

```
$badrooms=htmlspecialchars($_POST["badrooms"]);
$showers=htmlspecialchars($_POST["showers"]);
```

И тут, например такое условие:

```
если `$badrooms=1 и $showers=1` то переходим на `url://mysite.loc/hotel/index.html`
если `$badrooms=2` и `$showers=1` то переходим на `url://mysite.loc/hotel/index2.html`
если $badrooms=2 и $showers=2 то переходим `url://mysite.loc/hotel/index3.html`
а например я знаю, что у меня нет такой страницы  по данным  `$badrooms=2`  `$showers=3`
то выдать ошибку или переправить на `страницу 404`.
```

Как я понял правельный вариант это создавать БД, делать какой-то обработчик `result.php` и все результаты при нажатии на `input type submit` будут перенаправлять на `result.php` где скажем статичными будут `header` и `footer`,  а сам контент будет браться из БД. Но как с базами работать я вообще не понимаю пока (вроде создал через `phpmyadmin`, а вывести не получается). Вот и подумал,  если у меня всего выборка, то получается на 10 HTML страниц можно как то осуществлять переход на эти страницы через форму. Интересует сам процесс перехода  по условию.
Наверное еще JS код понадобится.

Надеюсь я более менее понятно описал задачу.

Где про это посмотреть конкретно? Или пример кода, чтобы знать откуда отталкиваться.

То есть еще раз, есть какие-то данные которые которые я получаю с формы, эти данные обрабатываются и выдают определенные HTML страницы (всего <15 страниц).

Comment: Может через цикл как то можно 'if $badrooms=1 { require('index1.html')}'?

Comment: Зачем вам 15 html файлов и забирать их через php. Разберитесь как работает php с бд через PDO. Заполните БД вашими даннЫми и после забирайте нужные данные с бд и выводите на страницу.

Comment: То-есть примерно так это будет: есть форма  нажимаю отправить. данные получает какой-то somfing.php и в нем  определенные запросы к базе данных и в нем же вывод этих данных на страницу?

Comment: Примерно так, но в somfing.php можно сделать 1 запрос в который будут передаваться данные из формы по которым будет происходить выборка из бд.

Comment: Спасибо буду смотреть, а потом как эти данные можно стилизовать ,чтобы выглядело так как на статичной странице. Можно просто  строчку  <div class="tittle_hotel">Название отеля </div> и вместо названия отеля  вставить  переменную?